# redis2_query & proxy_pass together

Tags: nginx, redis

I am trying to implement security to APIs via Nginx. Basically I will allow APIs only if a token exists in redis.

```
  location /api/ {
                if ($http_securitytoken = "") { return 403; }
                if ($http_securitytoken){
                             redis2_query get $http_securitytoken;
                             redis2_pass 127.0.0.1:6379;
                }

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003;
        }
```

The issue here is what I want is redis2_query results to a variable, instead it is sending response and my proxy_pass is not working anymore, instead the redis result is getting send as output.

How to resolve?

Comment: Do you really need that value in a variable for further processing? What is the HTTP result code in case the token is absent in redis database? Is it 200 or 404 or something else?

Comment: I dont need that value. All I need is just that token should be present in redis. but even the above code is not working. I am getting redis output as response from Nginx with above code.

Comment: If token in not prsenet, then 403 else go to the proxy_pass

Comment: Looks like you don't understand my second question. I didn't ask what HTTP code should be. What HTTP code you get when a given security token is absent in redis database with your current config?

Comment: Currently my Nginx config is not working. Basically I am getting 200 code with redis output as Output which is ":0" instead of actual API output

Comment: I had an idea to use [`ngx_http_auth_request_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) but if you get an HTTP 200 result code from `redis2_pass` no matter the token present in the redis database or not, it wouldn't work. Once again, do you receive HTTP 200 OK if security token isn't present in a database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216290/discussion-between-ankit-bansal-and-ivan-shatsky).